# Maximal ideals in the ring of Gaussian integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R= \{  a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ be a subring of $\mathbb{C}$. Consider two principal ideals $I=(7)$ and $J=(13)$ in $R$. Is the ideal $I$ maximal? How about $J$?

I don't understand what $I=(7)$ or $J=(11)$ means. Aren't there both $a$ and $b$ to be considered? Why is there only one number?

I know that an ideal $M$ in a ring $R$ is maximal if $M \ne R$ and whenever if $N$ is also an ideal such that $M \subseteq N \subseteq R$, then $M=N$ or $N=R$. So if I can understand what these ideals are I can probably figure out which one is maximal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $(7)$ is the ideal generated by $7$. In this case $$(7)=\{ 7a+7bi|a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \} \,.$$

Comment: $I = \{(a+ib)\cdot 7 : a, b \in  \mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

$\mathbb Z[i]$ is a PID. If $(7)$ or $(13)$ is not maximal, it can be included in some larger ideal $(m)$.

This means that $m|7$ or $m|11$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$. Now all you need is to figure out if you can find $a+bi$ and $c+di$ which are not units and

$$(a+bi)(c+di)=7$$
respectively
$$(a+bi)(c+di)=13$$

Comment: thank you! So I was able to find 3 and 2 for 11 therefore 11 is not maximal. 7 is indeed a maximal.

Answer (score 3):

hint: $13=(2+3i)(2-3i)$. Does this help you? Is the ideal (13) maximal from this? It might help to note that the Gaussian integers are an Euclidean domain and hence prime ideals are maximal.