# Maximal Ideals in $R=\{a+bi:a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I've read similar question but please this is not duplicate of [Maximal ideals in the ring of Gaussian integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591573/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-of-gaussian-integers) because the answer to it contain PID which I've not yet done etc.

> $R=\{a+bi:a,b\in \mathbb Z\}$ be a subring of $\mathbb C$ and $I=(7)$, $J=(13)$ in $R$. Is $I$ or $J$  maximal?

How to go with this?

Comment: Have you studied quotient rings? Also, what characterizations do you know of maximal ideals?

Comment: @user180040 i've studied quotient rings..About characterizations i'm yet to study

Comment: What I mean is, do you know that an ideal $M$ is maximal if and only if $R/M$ is a field?

Comment: @user180040 yes I know it...

Answer (score 2):

$(3 + 2i)(3 - 2i) \in J$, but $3+2i, 3-2i \not\in J$. This shows that the ideal $J$ is not prime. Therefore it cannot be maximal.

We prove that $R/I$ is a field. Let $a + bi \in R - I$, thus $a$ and $b$ cannot both be divisible by $7$. It is enough to show that $a + bi$ is invertible in $R/I$. But $(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2 + b^2$. The number $a^2 + b^2$ can be shown to be invertible in $\mathbf{Z}/(7)$, hence it is also invertible in $R/I$.

To prove this, write $x = \bar{a}, y = \bar{b}$ in $\mathbf{Z}/(7)$. We have $x, y \ne 0$. Now $x^2 + y^2 = x^2[1 + (y/x)^2]$. Thus it is enough to check that $1 + z^2 \ne 0$ for all $z \in \mathbf{Z}/(7)$, which is easy to do.

NOTE

A less elementary proof can be given by showing that the rings $R/I$ and $R/J$ are isomorphic respectively to $F_7[X]/(X^2 + 1)$ and $F_{13}[X]/(X^2 + 1)$. The first is a field because $X^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $F_7[X]$. The second is not because $X^2 + 1 = (X+5)(X-5)$ in $F_{13}[X]$. These methods rely however on the fact that $K[X]$ is a PID for any field $K$.